# Why does CloudFormation API Gateway fail stating 'The REST API doesn't contain any methods' even with DependsOn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have a CloudFormation template which I'm trying to deploy. This template is very similar to another template I have which works without issue however when deploying this template it keeps failing stating:

`APIGatewayDeployment5332c373d4                     CREATE_FAILED   The REST API doesn't contain any methods (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 02c0352f-b23b-44d5-a0af-2f3f3ecd7273)`

I had this issue previously on my other template and added the `DependsOn` property on the deployment which fixed the issue however even with this property this template is failing.

See cut down version of my template below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Globals:
  Function:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        FOO: bah
  Api:
    EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
Resources:
  APIGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: Some API
      StageName: !Sub ${EnvironmentTagName}
  ApiFooResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt APIGateway.RootResourceId
      PathPart: foo
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGateway
  ApiFooNotificationResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !Ref ApiFooResource
      PathPart: notification
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGateway
  ApiFooNotificationMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiFooNotificationResource
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGateway
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: '200'
      Integration:
        Credentials: !GetAtt SQSRole.Arn
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        Type: AWS
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sqs:action/SendMessage
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.querystring.QueueUrl: !Sub '''${FooNotificationQueue}'''
          integration.request.querystring.MessageBody: method.request.body
  ApiTestResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt APIGateway.RootResourceId
      PathPart: test
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGateway
  ApiTestMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiTestResource
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGateway
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: '200'
      Integration:
        Credentials: !GetAtt SQSRole.Arn
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        Type: AWS
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sqs:action/SendMessage
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.querystring.QueueUrl: !Sub '''${TestQueue}'''
          integration.request.querystring.MessageBody: method.request.body
  ApiDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn: ApiTestMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGateway
      Description: !Sub Api Deployment for ${EnvironmentTagName}
      StageName: !Sub ${EnvironmentTagName}

...**Removed the rest for brevity**...

Parameters:
  StackTagName:
    Type: String
    Description: Stack Name (injected by Stackery at deployment time)
  EnvironmentTagName:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment Name (injected by Stackery at deployment time)
```

Comment: Could you try changing the Type to `Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` under Resources -> APIGateway?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. As @salazarin suggested, changing from ```AWS::Serverless::Api``` to ```AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi``` fixes the issue but this is still not what I want.